# Android test automation without PC

Tags: android, automated-tests

Most android test automation needs the device connected with PC through USB.
Is there any solution to do it without PC when testing? Some setup still need PC.

Comment: check out robolectric https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric

Comment: what exactly you are looking for... an app testing in android or testing a web application in android or something else, be specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Raspberry-Pi, you will not need a PC. 
Try reading this blog:

[Raspberry-PI for Android Test Automation](http://innovation.avg.com/2016/06/15/raspberry-pi-for-android-test-automation/)